# Найти все нечетные числа в списке и прибавить к ним число

Tags: python

Написать функцию, которая находит все нечетные числа в списке и добавляет к ним единичку, а потом выводит новый список.

Так же функция должная содержать только одну перменную, то есть сам список

Comment: _В общем вопрос в заголовке_ - это не вопрос, а задание

Comment: Данный ресурс является ресурсом для ответов на вопросы, 
а не площадкой по решению заданий. 
Хотите, что бы кто-то за вас сделал вашу работу - 
обращайтесь к фрилансерам.

Вам следует прочесть следующие разделы справки: 
[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), 
[Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
После этого отредактируйте вопрос и приведите его к рекомендуемому виду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проходимся по каждому елементу с помощью `map()`.
Проверяем четное ли число или нет с помощью битовой операции **and** `x & 1` и прибавляем результат этой же операции (от либо 0, либо 1).

```
def find(arr):
    print([*map(lambda x: x + (x & 1), arr)])
```

Comment: можно так: `def f(l):return[*map(lambda x:x+x%2,l)]`

Comment: @Danis, я традиционным способом. Но можно и так.